# How to start my app with 2nd position fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had 3 Swipable Fragment in Activity when my app stats with first fragment but i need my app starts with second fragment please any one help me how to do this ,
Here below my code

when i app start my app open with first fragment ,but i my app with second fragment ,please tell me how to my app start with second fragment ,Thank You in Advance

MainActivity.java

```
 ViewPager viewpager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:

                return new OneFnew();

            case 1:
                return new TwoFNEW();
            case 2:
                return new ThreeFnew();

            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewpager.setCurrentItem(1)` should do the work for you.

Place this line after you initialize the adapter for the viewpager.